# Parenthesis Checker C++ program

Tags: c++, stack

I'm just learning to deal with stack and trying to implement some questions. I used this algorithm from geeks for geeks. In this Parenthesis Checker program. This is returning false for the input {([])}
Can somebody please help why.

```
bool ispar(string x)
{
    // Your code here
    stack<int> s;
    
    for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
        if(x[i]=='{' || x[i]=='[' || x[i]=='('){
            s.push(x[i]);
            continue;
        }
        if(s.empty()){
            return false;
        }
        switch(x[i]){
            case ')':{
                x = s.top();
                s.pop();
                if (x[i]=='{' || x[i]=='[') 
                    return false;
                break;
            }
            case '}':{
                x = s.top();
                s.pop();
                if(x[i] =='[' || x[i]=='(')
                    return false;
                break;
            }
            case ']':{
                x = s.top();
                s.pop();
                if(x[i] == '(' || x[i] =='{')
                    return false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return s.empty();
}
```

Comment: If ever there was a case for single-stepping with a *debugger*, this is it.

Comment: You assign into x in the loop, with the single character at the top of the stack, and then you continue looping on x. Also your conditions shouldn't be with `x[i] == '(' || x[i] == '{'` , it should be (assuming you save the top character into variable t) `t == '(' || t == '{'`

Comment: thank you sooo much..it was very silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

I changed `stack<int>` to `stack<char>`, and `s.top()` must be assigned to a `char`, not `string x`.

```
bool ispar(const std::string& x)
{
    // Your code here
    stack<char> s;
    char opening_char;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        if (x[i] == '{' || x[i] == '[' || x[i] == '(') {
            s.push(x[i]);
            continue;
        }

        if (s.empty()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (x[i]) {
        case ')': {
            opening_char = s.top();
            s.pop();
            if (x[i] == '{' || x[i] == '[')
                return false;
            break;
        }
        case '}': {
            opening_char = s.top();
            s.pop();
            if (x[i] == '[' || x[i] == '(')
                return false;
            break;
        }
        case ']': {
            opening_char = s.top();
            s.pop();
            if (x[i] == '(' || x[i] == '{')
                return false;
            break;
        }
        }
    }

    return s.empty();
}
```